# Function is not returning expected result

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have created function below which should return the status based on two inputs, but it always ends up in the last if statement. I can't figure out why it's ending in the last one. If I comment the last one, it ends up in one the above.

```
    //Function to check if margin is OK or not
function check_margin($vpc, $bruto_margin_avg) {
    if(($vpc >= 1 && $vpc <= 15000) && ($bruto_margin_avg >= 33 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 40)) {
        //IF VPC is between 0-15000kn and bruto margin is between 33-40%
        $bruto = 'OK';
        $comment = '1';
    } else {
        $bruto = 'NO';
        $comment = '33% - 40%';
    }

    if(($vpc >= 15000 && $vpc <= 50000) && ($bruto_margin_avg >= 0 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 2)) {
        $bruto = 'OK';
        $comment = '2';
    } else {
        $bruto = 'NO';
        $comment = '25% - 30%';
    }

    if(($vpc >= 50000 && $vpc <= 80000) && ($bruto_margin_avg >= 23 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 27)) {
        $bruto = 'OK';
        $comment = '3';
    } else {
        $bruto = 'NO';
        $comment = '23% - 27%';
    }

    if($vpc > 80000 && $bruto_margin_avg > 21) {
        $bruto = 'OK';
        $comment = '';
    } else {
        $bruto = 'NO';
        $comment = '> 21%';
    }

    return array($bruto, $comment);
}
```

My input parameters are this:

```
  $vpc = 1560.00;
  $bruto_margin_avg = 14.952937358001;
```

Based on the input results it should end up in the first if statement. What is wrong with the code below that is failing to deliver the proper result?

Comment: "$bruto_margin_avg = 14.952937358001" then it's not satisfy the first if

Comment: The execution of the function does not end in the if() block, the conditions in your function will be execution until "return" is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments in the question, I think what you actually want to do is test the value of `$vpc`, and then check whether the value of `$bruto_margin_avg` is appropriate for that value of `$vpc`. This code will do that:

```
// Function to check if margin is OK or not
function check_margin($vpc, $bruto_margin_avg) {
    if ($vpc >= 1 && $vpc <= 15000) {
        if ($bruto_margin_avg >= 33 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 40) {
        //IF VPC is between 0-15000kn and bruto margin is between 33-40%
            $bruto = 'OK';
            $comment = '1';
        } else {
            $bruto = 'NO';
            $comment = '33% - 40%';
        }
    }

    if ($vpc >= 15000 && $vpc <= 50000) {
        if ($bruto_margin_avg >= 0 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 2) {
            $bruto = 'OK';
            $comment = '2';
        } else {
            $bruto = 'NO';
            $comment = '25% - 30%';
        }
    }

    if ($vpc >= 50000 && $vpc <= 80000) {
        if ($bruto_margin_avg >= 23 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 27) {
            $bruto = 'OK';
            $comment = '3';
        } else {
            $bruto = 'NO';
            $comment = '23% - 27%';
        }
    }

    if ($vpc > 80000) {
        if ($bruto_margin_avg > 21) {
            $bruto = 'OK';
            $comment = '';
        } else {
            $bruto = 'NO';
            $comment = '> 21%';
        }
    }

    return array($bruto, $comment);
}

$vpc = 1560.00;
$bruto_margin_avg = 14.952937358001;
print_r(check_margin($vpc, $bruto_margin_avg));
```

Output

```
Array ( 
    [0] => NO 
    [1] => 33% - 40% 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MTGak)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted! I didn't think to put it in two if statements.

Answer (score 0):

As per your inputs first condition is not fulfill.

```
if(($vpc >= 1 && $vpc <= 15000) && ($bruto_margin_avg >= 33 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 40))
```

Below condition fullfill your inputs. but

```
($vpc >= 1 && $vpc <= 15000)
```

Below is not.

```
($bruto_margin_avg >= 33 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 40)
```

If you have to check any of one condition of both condition is true than u can use || operator. Like below.

```
if(($vpc >= 1 && $vpc <= 15000) || ($bruto_margin_avg >= 33 && $bruto_margin_avg <= 40))
```